# How to allow Typescript in the Dev Console to avoid Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Tags: typescript, devtools

Testing a block of Typescript code in the Chrome/Edge Dev Console throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'`:

[image: SyntaxError from Typescript use in Dev Console]

I am *not* expecting it to understand Typescript - ignoring the TS syntax would be fine.

It would be nice to be able to copy/paste snippits of TS code without having to reformat them as pure JS.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What do you expect? The code is ignored? Why to you paste ts code in dev console if the expectation is that would be ignored?

Comment: I suppose I should have said "ignore typescript _syntax_", as I would clearly want the code to be interpreted :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a browser extension whichs add Typescript into Devtools

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/console%2B/mdpcfmohggcepdncbognlniaiefdpnnf
https://github.com/madyanalj/console-plus
or
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/typescript-editor/amljndfnogpalkfjcfohnepgnhfcpamk

[image]

...I wish there was a better one, with snippets or maybe file access, honestly

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for a more native solution rather than an alternative to the existing console interface.

Comment: @JamesGentes like Devtools/Sources/Snippets (tab location) but in ts? Or what? Explair further please

Comment: @JamesGentes or like debugging in TS even if code itself is JS?

Comment: I use VSCode for debugging / dev, I'm simply looking for devtools to not puke when trying to interpret typescript